# "General::sysffmpeg: Using a limited version of FFmpeg" won't go away on Linux (MMA 12.3)

Tags: linux, installation, video

This issue appeared when I tried to render animation videos
using `Export` on Fedora.

```
$VideoEncoders["MP4"][[All, 1]]
General::sysffmpeg: Using a limited version of FFmpeg. Install FFmpeg to get more complete codec support.
```

The Wolfram community forum has a [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2188963) detailing the
installation of ffmpeg on Linux, but it was useless.

An internal variable can be used to check whether system ffmpeg is used:

```
FFmpegTools`$SystemFFmpegQ
False
```

ffmpeg 4.4.2 is installed and working and should be compatible  (4.4.2 >= 4.0.0), but Mathematica refuses to use it without
providing any meaningful error message to indicate what
the problem is, and

```
Internal`$LastInternalFailure
```

shows nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hacking `SystemFiles/Links/FFmpegTools/Kernel/Common.m` I managed to get a meaningful error message.

The problem is that Mathematica bundles shared libraries which are incompatible with system shared libraries. In this case, ffmpeg depends on kerberos, which depends on openssl, which Mathematica bundles.

The solution is to force Mathematica to use the system library.
Removing or renaming the offending shared library is all it takes.

```
sudo mv Mathematica/12.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.1 Mathematica/12.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.1.backup
```

Restart the kernel and you should be ok.

```
FFmpegTools`$SystemFFmpegQ (* True *)


$VideoEncoders["MP4"][[All, 1]] (* Check that more codecs are available *)
```