# High Quality animation with Export?

Tags: graphics, export, image-processing, animation, video

This is my second question here. Recently I've been trying to compile a video simulation of wave propagation via `ComplexPlot[]` with `Table[]`. Essentially I produced a set of images with `Table[]` and then exported it as  `.avi`. This would take upwards to 30 minutes to process but when all is set and done, I get a very very low quality, [pixelated video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYf2R.jpg) and I wanted to ask if I could remedy this because the images from the `Table[]` seem very high res.

Here's my code for the plot and my Export settings

```
plot1 = Table[ComplexPlot[((1 - Abs[z]^2)/Abs[1 - z*Exp[-I*Pi/4]]^2)^((1 + I*4)/2)*Exp[-I*(1 + 4^2)*t], {z, -1 - I, 1 + 1 I}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, MeshFunctions -> Function[{z}, Abs[z]],Mesh -> {{0.9}}, MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, ColorFunction -> {Automatic, None}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t,0, 2, 2/2000}];
`Export["hpw_2.avi", plot1, CompressionLevel -> 0, FrameRate -> 60, Antialiasing -> True, ImageResolution -> 500, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]
```

I've tried everything from increasing ImageResolution to increasing PlotPoints but both the plot as well as the legend turns out blurry.

**Edit:**
It seems that I solved my problem by exporting in .mp4 format for quality as @Mariusz. Additionally, installing the full version of ffmeg as @Chris K mentioned has made computations much faster. Thank you!

Comment: `avi` format is very  old use `mp4`.Try:`Export["hpw_3.mp4", plot1, CompressionLevel -> 0, FrameRate -> 60, 
 Antialiasing -> True, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]`

Comment: Recently, I also wanted to optimize some animated videos.  As @MariuszIwaniuk noted, I found that `mp4` was best.  Furthermore, installing the full version of `ffmpeg` was well-worth the trouble, as the output was better and much smaller.  See, e.g., [this doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingVideo.html#1156435029) and [this community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2189605), and [this M.SE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263030/ffmpeg-installation-mathematica-13-0) for more info.

Comment: @ChrisK When I first started exporting video, mathematica asked me if I wanted to install ffmeg so I said yes. Now given that, should I also manually install ffmeg as suggested by the doc you mentioned?

Comment: @dd5 I’d give it a try - it was a minor pain but ultimately worth it. The community post I linked shows how to tell if you have the full version or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a video directly and save memory and time, you could also try something like

```
Parallelize@
 AnimationVideo[
  Rasterize@
   ComplexPlot[((1 - Abs[z]^2)/Abs[1 - z*Exp[-I*Pi/4]]^2)^((1 + I*4)/
        2)*Exp[-I*(1 + 4^2)*t], {z, -1 - I, 1 + 1 I}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{z}, Abs[z]], Mesh -> {{0.9}}, 
    MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, 
    ColorFunction -> {Automatic, None}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}],
  {t, 0, 2},
  CompressionLevel -> 0, FrameRate -> 60, DefaultDuration -> 30,
  GeneratedAssetLocation -> "vid.mp4"
  ]
```

Comment: Nice, BTW, that took my computer about 4 hours to do.