# Export animation to avi

Tags: export, animation, video

I'm trying to export an animation but the output is always `$Failed` with the error message:

```
Export: The value Automatic specified for the option AudioEncoding is invalid
```

Here is my code:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\ffmpeg-mathematica-master\\FFmpeg.m"];
m1 = Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
Export["test.avi", m1]
```

I think is valid to mention that I installed FFmpeg from an external source following Yogesh Patil's answer to [this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263030/ffmpeg-installation-mathematica-13-0). Also, when I verify the FFmpeg version in my command prompt using `ffmpeg - version`, this message appears:

```
    [NULL @ 000001fce09c9a80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

I'm not sure if that affects what I'm trying to do in Mathematica

Comment: You are almost there. Put `Animate` instead of `Manipulate` and it will work. Take care to be patient, since the formation of the avi fail takes time.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch i've tried that change, but I still get `$Failed` as an output and the mentioned error message: `Export: The value Automatic specified for the option AudioEncoding is invalid`

Comment: This works for me: Mma 13.2, Win10.